# Performance-minded way to draw a scaled image in a JPanel

Tags: java

I have a Java Application that includes functionality to load in photos to show a user that they choose, but I want the width of each photo to be a max of 200 pixels.

My current solution is to use a class that subclasses `JPanel`, and in its constructor, I load the image and calculate the correct size.

I override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` and draw the image there using:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
g.drawImage(image.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_FAST), 0, 0, this);
```

However, this resizes the image once every frame, since `paintComponent` is called every frame, and I’d prefer to only have to resize the image once and draw that.

Is there a way to achieve better performance, doing what I need it to do?

Comment: Why don't you store the result of `image.getScaledInstance` somewhere? Unless `width`/`height` can change this is should be safe to do in the constructor

Comment: But afaik `paintComponent` only gets called when the component updates, i.e. the component gets resized. If your monitor runs at 60Hz, I highly doubt that `paintComponent` actually gets called 60 times per second

Comment: @msrd0 I tried that and it draws nothing that way.

Comment: Also - using a `System.out.println()` statement spams the console.

Comment: " I tried that and it draws nothing that way." I dont know what you are doing because "Why don't you store the result of image.getScaledInstance somewhere? Unless width/height can change this is should be safe to do in the constructor" is a correct approach - why dont you show some stuff?

Comment: Actually - I found out what I was doing. Turns out, storing it locally actually worked. Before, it was just painting nothing, but I re-did it and it worked? I'm honestly not sure what happened differently but your solution worked. Thank you!